# p value sensitive analysis

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, p-value, simulation

I have simple design, two arm, $A$ vs $B$.

I am estimating the total $n = n_a + n_b$ to be 50.

The endpoint is binary ($Yes = 1$ or $No = 0$).

My Hypothesis is
$H_o: p_a-p_b=0 $ vs $H_a : p_a - p_b \not= 0$

This is a simple two sample proportion test.

I am interested in **estimating p** values for a range of scenarios

1. all possible combinations of endpoints $(0...50)$
2. assuming $n_a:$ could be either one of these values $(20 , 21 , 22 , 23 , 24 , 25 , 26 , 27 , 28 , 29
    , 30)$. Please note if $n_a=20, n_b=30$ , if  $n_a=21, n_b=29$, if  $n_a=22, n_b=28$..so on

Obviously I could estimate the p values for a range of possible endpoints and $n_a$ values manually but as we all know this will be very inefficient and prone to error. Is there a way to generate the **p values** for a range of values based on this scenario programmatically ??

Please help. Thanks.